Can `std::from_chars` not handle hexadecimal floating-point numbers?
The following program
#include <charconv>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "0X1.BC70A3D70A3D7P+6";
    std::cout << "strtod: " << std::strtod(s.c_str(), nullptr) << std::endl;
    double d = 42;
    std::from_chars(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), d, std::chars_format::general);
    std::cout << "from_chars: " << d << std::endl;
}

prints
strtod: 111.11
from_chars: 0

when compiled with GCC on Linux. Can std::from_chars not handle hexadecimal floating-point numbers?

As per std::from_chars it doesn't handle the leading 0X.

@Eljay only if fmt is std::chars_format::hex if I understood that documentation correctly

if fmt is std::chars_format::hex, the prefix "0x" or "0X" is not permitted (the string "0x123" parses as the value "0" with unparsed remainder "x123")

@AhmedAEK if fmt is std::chars_format::hex.  In the OP it is std::chars_format::general

@AhmedAEK fmt is not std::chars_format::hex here

doesn't look like any implementation tries to parse 0X , also "0x" or "0X" prefixes are not recognized if base is 16

looking here it seems like most/all compilers just don't support floating point yet.  although it does look like libstdc++ should support its so it could be a bug in the implementation

@NathanOliver decimal floating-point is working fine for me

If you look at the result returned from std::from_chars, you'll see that it "consumed" the first character (the 0), was unable to parse the X and stopped there, and set the d output argument to the value 0.0 (which was from the converted 0).  No errors encountered.  I'm using g++ 14.2.0.

@eyelash Looks like a bug.  If you remove the 0X and set hex format all 3 compilers get it right: https://godbolt.org/z/qEhhvYc4d

@NathanOliver does the standard say that it must parse the 0X ? could 2 major compilers and cppref all be wrong on this ?

@AhmedAEK cppref states Floating-point parsers: Expects the pattern identical to the one used by std::strtod.  trying to find where it says in the standard

@AhmedAEK found it.  Looks like cppref and the standard agree.

The important part is https://eel.is/c++draft/charconv#to.chars-3 -- the std::chars_format::general expects the string to be in %g format.  That's not a hex format.

@Eljay that part is under a section called "Primitive numeric output conversion". Does this really apply to std::from_chars?

That entire section is about std::from_chars and std::to_chars, so I think it applies.

@Eljay there is a section right after it called "Primitive numeric input conversion" that talks about std::from_chars so I'm assuming section 28.2.2 is only about converting numbers to strings.

The entire 28.2 is about std::from_chars and std::to_chars, inclusive of 28.2.1, 28.2.2, and 28.2.3.  Those functions are the primitive numeric conversions functions that are being discussed.

Don't throw away the return value:auto [next, err]=std::from_chars(first, last, &d, std::chars_format::hex); then: assert((next==last)); or just std::cout<<std::distance(first, next);.
